# box auth_token, acess token exired , unvalid

Tags: box-api

I send the following url to the box for getting an auth token

```
$.ajax({ url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%20%3D%20'https%3A%2F%2Fwww.box.net%2Fapi%2F1.0%2Frest%3Faction%3Dget_ticket%26api_key%3D" + api_key + "'&amp;format=json&amp;diagnostics=true", 
         dataType: 'jsonp', 
         success: function (result) {
```

I get the following result:

"http://www.clickmobileweb/HelloWorld.htm?ticket=vgn727u6twb33b26kxhqetmd15kf55xw&auth_token=azx85uq7nk3o0roa3rlh8hc6em38e0fs"

I get the auth token , and then I can use it for using box api. For how many days is this Access token(Auth token) valid ? When does it expire?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the V1 API, which will be deprecated in a month and a half. You should use the V2 AP which uses OAuth and has documented token lengths here: developers.box.com/oauth